# Query (tweak) help: MySQL - replace portion of string instead of removing it

Tags: mysql

I have a column of string/text data..

Table: fulllog
Column: alldata

Some/many (but not all) of the rows have a value of "SOMEVAL1" in it...

I need to replace the 'value' that comes after it to a static 'N/A' text

Example of string data/structure:

```
[xxxx1] => x1 [xxxx2] => x2 [SOMEVAL1] => 123 [SOMEVAL2] => x3 [xxx3] => x4
```

or

```
[xxxx1] => x1 [xxxx2] => x2 [SOMEVAL1] => 1234 [SOMEVAL2] => x3 [xxx3] => x4
```

Basically can have 3 or 4 numbers

So in the end it looks like so:

```
[xxxx1] => x1 [xxxx2] => x2 [SOMEVAL1] => N/A [SOMEVAL2] => x3 [xxx3] => x4
```

I tried to use REGEX_REPLACE... but apparently not supported here?

I have this attempt at a QUERY.. which removes it.. but I'm not clear on how I can tweak the query to **REPLACE** that value?

Used **SELECT** statement and an ID selector in the WHERE clause to test my results on a specific row first

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(alldata, 1, INSTR(alldata, '[SOMEVAL1]') - 1), SUBSTR(alldata, INSTR(alldata, '[SOMEVAL2]'))) AS test FROM fulllog WHERE alldata LIKE '%\[SOMEVAL1\]%' AND id = '1056';
```

example of working SET/UPDATE query:

```
UPDATE fullog SET alldata = CONCAT(SUBSTR(alldata, 1, INSTR(alldata, '[VAL1]') + 9), 'N/A', SUBSTR(alldata, INSTR(alldata, '[VAL2]') - 1)) WHERE alldata LIKE '%[VAL1]%' AND id = '14';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You almost get it :**

```
CREATE table fulllog(
    id int,
    alldata text
);

insert into fulllog value
(1056,'[xxxx1] => x1 [xxxx2] => x2 [SOMEVAL1] => 123 [SOMEVAL2] => x3 [xxx3] => x4');
```

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(SUBSTR(alldata, 1, INSTR(alldata, '[SOMEVAL1]') + 13), 'N/A', SUBSTR(alldata, INSTR(alldata, '[SOMEVAL2]') - 1)) AS test 
FROM fulllog 
WHERE alldata LIKE '%\[SOMEVAL1\]%' AND id = '1056';
```

**RESULT :**

```
[xxxx1] => x1 [xxxx2] => x2 [SOMEVAL1] => N/A [SOMEVAL2] => x3 [xxx3] => x4
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16dc6c/1)

Just one question, what is your current version of MySQL ?

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you for the update/advice!  (accepted)

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to convert it to an UPDATE statement?

    UPDATE fullog CONCAT(SUBSTR(alldata, 1, INSTR(alldata, '[VAL1]') + 9), 'N/A', SUBSTR(alldata, INSTR(alldata, '[VAL2]') - 1)) WHERE alldata LIKE '%\[VAL1\]%' AND id = '14';

Comment: EDIT:  I see I didnt SET anything.. (DUH)